# USBドングルをWifi化することはできますか？

Tags: usb, wifi

解決したいこと
USBドングルを使用して複数のパソコン、スマホに繋げてインターネットを利用したいです。

例）
USBドングルをパソコンに接続し、パソコンを親機としてアクセスポイント化する。

自分で試したこと
パソコンにUSBドングルを接続し、インターネット利用はできますが、Wifi化することができません。

なにか良い方法はないでしょうか。

Comment: [ドングル](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%89%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AB)とは小型機器という意味しかありません。USB 無線LAN子機のことを指しているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

ドングルが「アクセスポイントモード」に対応した製品である必要があるのと、アクセスポイントに設定したのとは別に (有線などでの) ネットワーク接続が必要になると思います。

参考
http://qa.elecom.co.jp/sp/faq_detail.html?id=4683